# ROS2 rplidar subscriber doesn't receive topic /scan

Tags: ubuntu, ros

we are currently working on a project where we want to read the data of the rplidar sensor with ROS2 foxy on ubuntu 20.04 server on a Raspberry pi 4.
Therefore we got the official rplidar package from github for ROS2. It works and we can also see it in the topic list and get the data of the /scan topic with

```
ros2 topic echo /scan
```

We want to create a new node with one subscriber to the /scan topic. However the binded callback function is never called.

So we know that the topic is published, but we cannot bind it in our own node.

```
Minimal_sub::Minimal_sub() : Node("minimal_sub") {
_subscriber = create_subscription<Sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan>("scan", 10, bind(&Minimal_sub::callback, this, std::placeholder::_1));
}

void Minimal_sub::callback(const Sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan::SharedPtr msg) {
std::cout << "Received Message << std::endl;
}
```

Thanks for every small hint.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the *full* topic name. In your example you're using the topic `"scan"` which is relative to the node's namespace. Instead you want to use the fully qualified topic name, i.e. `"/scan"`. The following is what you want:

```
Minimal_sub::Minimal_sub() : Node("minimal_sub") {
    _subscriber = create_subscription<Sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan>("/scan", 10, bind(&Minimal_sub::callback, this, std::placeholder::_1));
}

void Minimal_sub::callback(const Sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan::SharedPtr msg) {
    std::cout << "Received Message << std::endl;
}
```